# pyspark optimization for exceptAll

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a simple PySpark code using default Spark standalone config.

There are 2 files both around 2GB in size:

- `df1` - load `file1`
- `df2` - load `file2`

then find unique data from `df1` dataframes:

```
df3 = df1.exceptAll(df2)
df3.show()
```

Is there a way to make this code run faster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which columns are you using to find the uniqueness? You may not need to check all the columns. You can select the columns used for uniqueness and then use `exceptAll` to increase performance.